# Allocate Multiple Arrays with Single Shape

Tags: fortran

I am allocating several rank-3 arrays to be exactly the same shape, and I wonder whether it's possible to specify the shape only once. For example, I'm currently doing:

```
program main
   implicit none
   integer :: long_name_dimension_1 = 3
   integer :: long_name_dimension_2 = 5
   integer :: long_name_dimension_3 = 8

   real, allocatable, dimension(:,:,:) :: A, B, C

   allocate(A(long_name_dimension_1,long_name_dimension_2,long_name_dimension_3), &
            B(long_name_dimension_1,long_name_dimension_2,long_name_dimension_3), &
            C(long_name_dimension_1,long_name_dimension_2,long_name_dimension_3))

end program main
```

This is annoying to type, and it's difficult to immediately see that these arrays have the same shape. I could use mold or source, after allocating the first array, such as:

```
allocate(A(long_name_dimension_1,long_name_dimension_2,long_name_dimension_3))
allocate(B, source=A)
allocate(C, mold=A)
```

but I don't really like this either - perhaps because, in my mind, it should be one `allocate` statement.

I'm looking for syntax such as:

```
allocate( SHAPE :: (long_name_dimension_1,long_name_dimension_2,long_name_dimension_3), &
   A, B, C)
```

which I've been unable to find. Does such a syntax (or something similar) exist?

Comment: I suggest you to download a copy of the Fortran Standard there and check the allocate statement part. I'll do that too, but I don't think there is such a thing. https://wg5-fortran.org

Comment: Thats a good point - I have checked the standard and didn't see anything I thought answered my question. However, I find it difficult to interpret some parts of the standard. The 'allocate' section has a *lot* of possible forms.

Comment: I just edited my answer, check it!

Comment: The simple answer is 'no'.  A longer answer is that you don't need to use variables that contain 20+ characters.  BTW, you could do allocate(b, c, mold=a) or simply rely on allocate-on-assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is the syntax for the allocate statement in the last (2015) Fortran Standard:

[image: allocate statement in Fortran 2015]

The shape must follow each *allocation* term in *allocation-list*, so there isn't any syntax structure for declaring one common shape for all the variables, except with the `SOURCE` or `MOLD` options.

> I could use mold or source, after allocating the first array, but I
>   don't really like this either - perhaps because, in my mind, it should
>   be one allocate statement.

Actually, you cannot define the shape of an array and reference it in the same statement. Later in this same chapter, it says:

> *source-expr* shall not be allocated within the ALLOCATE statement in
>   which it appears; nor shall it depend on the value, bounds, deferred
>   type parameters, allocation status, or association status of any
>   *allocate-object* in that statement.

So, summing up, the closest thing to what you want is exactly what you don't like:

```
allocate(A(long_name_dimension_1,long_name_dimension_2,long_name_dimension_3))
allocate(B, C, mold=A)
```

Or source=A, if you want the contents of A to be copied on.

---

**Edit:**

What about this:

```
allocate(A, B, C, mold=reshape([integer ::], &
[long_name_dimension_1,long_name_dimension_2,long_name_dimension_3])
```

I just checked in Intel Fortran and confirmed it works. It seems strange that a zero-sized array can have any shape. I strongly believe it's not standard, though.

Comment: Can you explain the syntax in your edit? You’re declaring an integer with the desired shape to mold to?

Comment: An obvious way to anwer your question is having a variable with your desired shape to use it as a mold, but an obvious deficiency of this approach is that you would end up with this useles variable occupying storage (posibly a lot of storage if the dimensions are large). So, I'm trying to find a solution that have low memory impact; That's why I came with the zero-sized idea. But I strongly believe that its not Standard. `reshape([integer ::], [m, n, o], [0])` does work, but also allocates the whole array. I'll keep searching.

Comment: Ah, I see, the variable you’re reshaping is a 0-length array.

Comment: The last published Fortran standard is informally known as F2008, and was formally published in 2010. The next revision, which is yet to be published, was once referred to as Fortran 2015, but is now informally referred to as Fortran 2018.

Comment: indeed, @HighPerformanceMark. But including the pad allocates the array and eliminates the "clever" part. I also tried null(mold) and a disassociated rebounded pointer... but I give up. There is no (standard conforming) way to have a variable with a non-zero shape descriptor without having the storage allocated.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. To clarify, I definitely don't see the OP as a significant problem, I just wanted to know whether such a syntax exists. I chose to accept this answer, but thanks to both.

Answer (score 3):

Fortran doesn't support allocating multiple arrays as you would like it to.  You're just about stuck with the `mold` and `source` options to the `allocate` statement.  You could write

```
allocate(A(long_name_dimension_1,long_name_dimension_2,long_name_dimension_3))
allocate(B,C,mold=A)
```

which saves a few keystrokes.  You could save a few more by writing

```
allocate(A(long_name_dimension_1,long_name_dimension_2,long_name_dimension_3))
A = 1
B = A
C = A
```

albeit that this sets the values of the elements of `B` and `C` as well as their shapes.

I edited the code to deal with the issue @evets raised in a comment.

Comment: The code in the 2nd example is invalid.  'a' has not been defined.

Comment: @evets Mark's code is completely clear to me - I even define `A` in the initial question. Why would you bother with such a meaningless negative comment?

Comment: @Ross  Mark's code is invalid.  'a' is allocated, but not defined.  It is invalid to reference an undefined entity.  Mark needs to set 'a' to some value, e.g., 'a = 0'.  Ross, please read the Fortran standard to learn what 'not defined' means.

Comment: Ah, I would think of that as 'uninitialized'. I am just trying to allocate arrays in a more convenient manner - is it a problem if they end up undefined?

Comment: @Ross, 'uninitialized' and 'not defined' are the same thing here.  If you're trying to write standard conforming Fortran, 'a' needs to be defined before it is referenced (except under a few well defined situations).  I really don't understand why 3 allocate statements are issue.  Try defining 3 3-diimensional dynamic arrays in C.  It takes more than 3 lines.